# How to use commander.js command through npm command

Tags: npm, npm-scripts, node-commander

I'm using commander.js command like this `./index.js --project mono --type item --title newInvoice --comments 'Creates an invoice' --write`, Now I'm using the command through `npm run item newInvoice` by setting some options in `package.json` file like this

```json
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "snapshot": "node --max-old-space-size=10240 ./scripts/snapshot.js",
    "item": "./index.js --project mono --type item --title",
    "config": "./index.js --project mono --type config --title"
}
```

But whenever I'm trying to get the `--write` option with npm using `npm run item newInvoice --write` it's showing `undefined` for `--write`

Source Code:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node
const fs = require('fs');
const program = require('commander');
require('colors');

program
  .version('0.1.0')
  .option('--project [project]', 'Specifies the project name', 'mono')
  .option('--type [type]', 'Type of code to generate, either "item" or "config"', /^(config|item)$/, 'config')
  .option('--title [title]', 'Title of the item or config', 'untitled')
  .option('--comments [comments]', 'Configs: describe the config', '@todo description/comments')
  .option('--write', 'Write the source code to a new file in the expected path')
  .option('--read', 'To see what would be written the source code to a new file in the expected path')
  .parse(process.argv);

console.log(program.write, program.read); //=> undefined undefined
```

Can anyone help me how to use commander js command with npm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run your `npm run` command you need to utilize the special `--` option to demarcate the end of any option(s) that *may* belong to the `npm run` command itself (e.g. `--silent`), and the beginning of the argument(s) that are to be passed to the *end* of the npm script.

Run the following command instead:

```
npm run item -- newInvoice --write
```

Given the aforementioned command and the command currently defined your npm script named `item` they essentially form the following compound command prior to execution:

```
./index.js --project mono --type item --title newInvoice --write
                                              ^          ^
```

---

The [`npm run`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script) documentation states the following:

> *As of npm@2.0.0, you can use custom arguments when executing scripts. The special option `--` is used by [getopt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147143/when-and-how-was-the-double-dash-introduced-as-an-end-of-options-delimiter) to delimit the end of the options. npm will pass all the arguments after the `--` directly to your script.*

and it's usage syntax is defined in the *Synopsis* section as:

> ```
> npm run-script <command> [--silent] [-- <args>...]
>                                      ^^
> ```

**Note:** It's *not* possible to add the `--` option to the npm script itself.